# Bookshelf js model causes save/changed loop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bookshelf.js

The following Bookshelf model hashes the users password when the model is saved, the only problem is that if I change that `model.set()` call to a `model.save()` it goes into an infinite save/changed loop.

```js
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasTimestamps: true,

    constructor: function() {
        var self = this;
        bookshelf.Model.apply(this, arguments);

        this.on('saving', function(model) {
            if(!model.get('password')) {
                return self.hashPassword(model);
            }
        });
    },

    hashPassword: function(model) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(error, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(model.attributes.password, salt, function(error, hash) {
                model.set({password: hash});
                console.log(model.attributes);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I know that Backbone has a `silent: true` option you can pass so that `save()` doesn't trigger a changed event but I don't think Bookshelf supports it.

How can I save the changes `model.set()` has made without causing a save/changed loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that the model is saving before the hash_password method has returned a value, so I promiseified the bcrypt code like so:

```js
hashPassword: function(password) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(error, salt) {
            if(error) return reject(error);

            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(error, hash) {
                if(error) return reject(error);
                return resolve(hash);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

and completely refactored the model's constructor to use it:

```js
constructor: function() {
    var self = this;
    bookshelf.Model.apply(this, arguments);

    this.on('saving', function(model) {
        if(!model.attributes.password) {
            delete model.attributes.password;
        } else {
            return self.hashPassword(model.attributes.password)
            .then(function(hash) {
                model.set({ password: hash });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps somebody :-)